# Join two tables based on date from first

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables like below (date format: yyyy-MM-dd):

1) Table1 - SURGERY

```
P_ID        | SURGERY_DATE
------------------------------------------------
1           | 2012-04-01
2           | 2012-08-14
1           | 2012-07-22
4           | 2012-10-30
3           | 2012-06-07
```

2) Table2 - VISIT

```
P_ID        | VISIT_DATE 
-----------------------------------------
1           | 2012-03-28 
1           | 2012-04-14
1           | 2012-05-17
1           | 2012-09-12 
3           | 2012-07-15 
4           | 2012-10-10 
3           | 2012-06-01
```

The tables SURGERY and VISIT are joined from other tables. I would like to find all records that meet the following criteria: VISIT_DATE >= SURGERY_DATE

3) Result table

```
EMPLOYEE_ID | SUGERY_DATE | NUMBER OF VISIT
-------------------------------------------------------
1           | 2012-04-01 |    4
2           | 2012-08-14 |    0
1           | 2012-07-22 |    2
4           | 2012-10-30 |    1
3           | 2012-06-07 |    1
```

Comment: Please show us your code and indicate where you are having trouble.

Comment: Your logic is not clear, Why the number of visit for the second 1 is 2? it must be 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*,
       (select count(*)
        from visit v
        where v.p_id = s.p_id and v.visit_date > s.surgery_date
       ) as num_visits_after
from surgery s;
```

Comment: should not consider visits before previous surgery

Answer (score 1):

Using group by and count can solve your problem.

Please try the code below.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFzdf.jpg)

Comment: Please do not post the code as image but as plain text.

Comment: I'm sorry I have a hard time to post the answer because the stackoverflow says there's an invalid character in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use group by and count with a mentioned condition like the following:

```
SELECT
    S.P_ID,
    S.SURGERY_DATE,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN V.VISIT_DATE > S.SURGERY_DATE THEN 1
    END) AS NUM_VISITS_AFTER
FROM
    SURGERY S
    LEFT JOIN VISIT V ON ( S.P_ID = V.P_ID )
GROUP BY
    S.P_ID,
    S.SURGERY_DATE;
```

Cheers!!